# Documents open in both the browser and client

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document, office-web-apps, client

My SharePoint 2013 site collection had been set to open all documents in the client application (by activating the site collection feature). After installing some security patches the other day, documents now open in **both** the browser and client at the same time!

I have tried deactivating and reactivating the feature but still the same results. Has anyone come across this before or knows how to fix it?

Comment: What patches did you apply?

Comment: It was the May cumulative update which includes KB3039780

Comment: Did you have installed SharePoint 2013 ServicePack 1 before you installed the May 2015 Cumulative Update? You also have to run the SharePoint Products configuration Wizard on every Server of your Farm after installing SharePoint related updates.

Comment: weired thing is why 2 copies open...cople of things to check...did you change any config file on sharepoint servers before upgrade? what is browser file handling( strict or permissive)? did your config wizard complered without error?

Comment: I forgot to run the config wizard after the update. I have just done this and it has produced some errors so I will fix them first before I address this issue. Service pack 1 was already installed and browser file handling is set to permissive